# Save changes to Repository level GIT Config

Tags: git, config

I ran this command

```
git config --local merge.ours.driver true
```

It is supposed to make a change in the .git\config file (which is the repository level configuration file). It does make this change.

I can see this change when I run

```
git config --list
```

But I do not see this change when I run the same list command from a different user's machine. How can I persist this change across the repository?

It does not show up in 'pending changes', so I cannot check in this change. Is the .git folder being "ignored" ? I couldn't find it in the .gitignore.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration file `.git/config` is not itself a version-controlled file.

It *can't* be, on a fairly fundamental level: it has to exist, and to be full of data, before you start doing any version-controlling.  It *could* refer to (i.e., include, or even be switched with) a version-controlled file after that point, but Git doesn't do that.

What you can do is provide a script that runs whatever configuration items should be run, and commit that script to the repository.  Users can then run the script, which can check and correct their configuration as necessary.

(I will also note here that if you are setting up a `merge.ours.driver` like this, you are probably in for a bit of a shock later when Git uses their version during a merge.  Git does not invoke custom drivers unless there are changes on *both sides* of a merge.  If there is a one-sided change, i.e., to their version but not to ours, Git just takes the change.)

Comment: What is the purpose of having a repository level config file if it cannot persist the changes then? How can I configure repository GIT settings?

For your tip about merge ours driver, you're right. I am using that to lock files while branches are merged, ideally these files will not be touched after the first time configuration, so they should never be picked up by GIT even though they are different. If they are changed, yes, GIT will pick it up and the user has to manually merge it as needed.

Comment: *What is the purpose of having a repository level config file ...*  To configure settings for the repository. But the settings are *per repository*, not copied to other clones. That would make no sense: for instance, if I clone your repository, I should not get your branch settings. I have my *own* branches, with my *own* settings. (A better point here is that the merge drivers should not be configured in `.git/config` in the first place: they're *driven from* `.gitattributes`, which is version-controlled, so they should be *definable within* `.gitattributes`.)

Comment: I understand now that repository is a local entity - not a server entity. The merge entries for files are in .gitattributes, but the driver to enable them has to be in the config [merge "ours"]  driver = true. Is there a way it can be moved to the gitattributes?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. That's why I say that this is a better point, or better question: they *should* be in something version-controlled, like `.gitattributes`. It's a historical mistake that they are in `.git/config` instead.

Comment: you can force your users to add it to their global git config via process or place a script in your repo to do it. It's a trade off, a tool with all the options but doesn't work, or git which works but has some minor flaws.